# Pyrocms front end controller - can't output image to the browser

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms, gd2

here is the code code below

```
class Home extends Public_Controller
{
    /**
     * Constructor method
     *`enter code here`
     * @author PyroCMS Dev Team
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }


public function testimg(){
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
    imagepng($image);     
}
}
```

but when i call this controller like (http://localhost/sitename/home/testimg).
i got the error below

The image "http://localhost/sitename/home/testimg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Kindly help me with this issue i am new to pyrocms.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem Solved :** there was always an extra **space** when echo something, i don't know why - **ob_clean()** does the job.

```
public function testimg(){
    ob_clean();
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
    imagepng($image);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to do with PyroCMS or even CodeIgniter, you've just set up the image wrong. That is a generic PHP error.

Comment: thanks for your suggesion. but i think its not a generic php error because when i place this code in a seprate file it works perfactly. 

for example. 

<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
    imagepng($image);     
?>

this will output a black image with 200 width and 200 hight.

but in pyrocms controller its not working. 
any quick help will appriciated.

Thanks